# If table variables only have the scope of their batch, then why can I select from one after using GO?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-variable

I clearly misunderstand the difference between a batch and a session. I believe three things that cannot all be true at the same time:

1. It is very well known that table variable only have the scope of their batch.
2. The documentation reports, I believe correctly, that `GO` [marks the end of a batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver16).
3. The following script does not throw an error, even though `@t` should be out of scope

```sql
declare @t table (id int)
insert into @t values (1)
select * from @t
GO
select * from @t
```

[DB fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/eCONDymO).

Clearly I am mistaken about something, but what?

Comment: Seems a symptom of db<>fiddle ignoring the `GO`. Try that same script block in SSMS.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'll have to do that tomorrow. I don't have SSMS on this machine.

Comment: It is just treating it as an alias of `@t` and not giving it any special treatment - i.e. same as `select * from @t AS GO` https://dbfiddle.uk/uQ2gsy2N - the documentation is about specific tools

Comment: SSMS Says `(1 row affected)

(1 row affected)
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
Must declare the table variable "@t".`

Comment: you're supposed to create a new "window" in fiddle to separate batches

Comment: IF you move the GO to the line above trailing the first select it IS treated as an alias in SSMS also

Comment: or if you change the batch separator to something other than `GO` it will too. There is no prohibition on having the alias on a different line

Comment: You DO see the error in the dbfiddle if you change the syntax to put in the semi-colon (missing is deprecated anyway for T-SQL) i.e. `declare @t table (id int);
insert into @t values (1);
select * from @t;
go
select * from @t;`

Comment: ^ [same thought](https://dbfiddle.uk/xNaE9wwa).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GO` is a batch separator known to SSMS. If you try the first script block from your fiddle in SSMS, [it will fail - as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Addp4.png).

This seems to be a symptom of db<>fiddle ignoring `go` *in some cases*. Actually, in this specific case, it seems to be ignoring the carriage return *before* `go` and applying it as an alias to `@t` in the preceding line, as Martin suggested, [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/QlxMFGpr):

```
declare @t table (id int);
insert into @t values (1);
select go.* from @t as go;
select * from @t;
```

This is simply because db<>fiddle uses separate input areas, not `GO`, to separate batches. In fact your script fails by [adding a single character (properly terminating the insert)](https://dbfiddle.uk/xNaE9wwa):

```
declare @t table (id int)
insert into @t values (1)
select * from @t;
----------------^
go
select * from @t
```

There are other examples where `go` will definitely cause errors. [For example](https://dbfiddle.uk/qFVJqF4t):

```
create table #t(id int);
go
select * from #t;
```

There are a lot of limitations and behavior differences between the database engine, the supported tools that ship for SQL Server, and online tools like db<>fiddle. If you're trying to confirm what the documentation says, please use the supported tooling against supported versions of SQL Server, and [always terminate statements with statement terminators](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons) to minimize surprises. Online emulators are useful for demonstrating syntax but not for validating documented behavior.

Comment: I preach that statement termination SO much to developers. "but it is not needed...they say" then I get to "I told you so..." but hate that when it happens.

Comment: @Mark definitely same :-) ... seems people need a _real disaster_ before they become believers.

Comment: How about the mantra "Terminate or be terminated" :-)

Comment: I've seen a catch block in production code with `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION<cr/lf>THROW`, missing the semicolon after `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`. Devs seldom test exception handlers.

Comment: Recently I have been seeing long lines of SQL with multiple statements in the one line...scroll scroll scroll right 500 characters visually parsing...my head hurts